# Oracle JDBC performance of ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I was using so far something like this for querying my database that was working perfectly fine :

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(mySql);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

But then I needed to use the `rs.first();` in order to be able to iterate over my `rs` multiple times. So I use now

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(mySql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

My question is related to the performance of the two. What do I lose if I use the second option? Will using the second option have any negative effect in the code that I have written so far?

PS: Note that my application is a multi-user, database-intensive web application (on a Weblogic 10.3.4) that uses a back end Oracle 11g database.

Thanks all for your attention.

**UPDATE**

My maximum reslutset size will be less than 1000 rows and 15-20 columns

Comment: Why building a `List<POJO>` from ResultSet and then using that POJO instead, wherever you want, is not an option? It's always easier to handle `List<POJO>`, comparatively. I mean data-type stuff, passing the number of column, or name, doesn't apply there.

Comment: Yes, that was what I had in mind when asking the question. If I have a performance issue I will definitely use this approach

Comment: @AdeelAnsari, that may not be an option of the resultset is quite large.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - How big is each column?  If you figure that each row is 500 bytes (this will obviously depend on data types), 1000 rows is 500 kb per user.  If you've got 1000 simultaneous users, that's only 500 MB of storage which probably isn't prohibitive.  If you've got 1 million simultaneous users, on the other hand, that's 500 GB which is probably much more of a concern.  If your rows are 5000 bytes rather than 500, then you're talking about 5 GB of RAM which could be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Cave You have been a real help

Comment: @Santosh: If that's the case, pagination is your best bet. Just don't retrieve everything out at once. Simple, ain't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an Oracle cursor is a forward-only structure, in order to simulate a scrollable cursor, the JDBC driver would generally need to cache the results in memory if it wants to be able to ensure that the same results are returned when you iterate through the results a second time.  Depending on the number and size of the results returned from the query, that can involve a substantial amount of additional memory being consumed on the application server.  On the other hand, that should mean that iterating through the `ResultSet` a second time should be much more efficient than the first time.

Whether the extra memory required is meaningful depends on your application.   You say that the largest `ResultSet` will have 1000 rows.  If you figure that each row is 500 bytes (this will obviously depend on data types-- if your `ResultSet` just has a bunch of numbers, it would be much smaller, if it contains a bunch of long description strings, it may be much larger), 1000 rows is 500 kb per user.  If you've got 1000 simultaneous users, that's only 500 MB of storage which probably isn't prohibitive. If you've got 1 million simultaneous users, on the other hand, that's 500 GB which is probably means that you're buying a few new servers. If your rows are 5000 bytes rather than 500, then you're talking about 5 GB of RAM which could be a large fraction of the memory required on the application server to run your application.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - It depends on your needs.  If your `ResultSet` is small and you have plenty of RAM on the application servers, it may be perfectly reasonable to use scrollable result sets.  If not, you may need to consider other options.  Some systems may be able to close and re-open the `ResultSet` which forces Oracle to re-execute the query and may give different results if changes have been committed since the first query was executed.  Some systems may be able to cache a subset of the data (i.e. a subset of columns) in a local collection.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using scrollability (your second option), pay attention to this:

> Important: Because all rows of any scrollable result set are stored in
>   the client-side cache, a situation where the result set contains many
>   rows, many columns, or very large columns might cause the client-side
>   Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to fail. Do not specify scrollability for a
>   large result set.

Source: [Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm)